# Area of a region under the mapping $f$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Consider the function $f:\mathbb R^{2} \to \mathbb R^{2}$ given by $f(x,y)=\left(e^{x+y},e^{x-y}\right)$. Area of the image of the region $\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^{2} | 0<x,y<1\}$ under the mapping $f$ is

(1) 1

(2) $e-1$

(3) $e^{2}$

(4) $e^{2}-1$  .

We have, $f(0,0)=(1,1), f(1,0)=(e,e), f(0,1)=(e,e^{-1}), f(1,1)=(e^{2},1)$. Plot these four points & add any one of the diagonal. Then we get two triangles & find the area of them and adding we get the required area. But I can not get any one of the option. I must be wrong. But I could not understand that where my mistake.

I want to know correct answer with procedure & my fallacy...

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by integrating the Jacobian of $f$ over the unit square. Thus $$A = \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \left| \det \begin{bmatrix} e^{x+y} & e^{x-y} \\ e^{x+y} & -e^{x-y} \end{bmatrix} \right| \, dxdy$$ The integral is simpler to evaluate than it looks. You should also first show that $f$ is one-to-one.

Comment: Why 1st we show that $f$ is one-one? Are there any theorem about this?

Comment: @@Umberto P.) Please response...

Comment: This result is in any calculus textbook. See also the first theorem at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Substitution_for_multiple_variables

Answer (score 0):

the image of the region is not a rectangle! you can't compute it's area by dividing it to two triangles

Comment: A tetrahedron is a 3 dimensional figure, so that's clearly not the case.

Comment: Sorry......It is a quadrilateral figure....

Answer (score 0):

Start by determining how the target region looks. Do this by arguing that boundary of the given region maps to the the boundary of the target region, and consider the image of each part of the boundary (you'll have to figure out how to partition the boundary). When you have an idea of how it looks, it will be a lot easier to figure how how to calculate it's area.